# Using Jquery + Json to make instances?

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I have a JSONP file that is pulling data about Venues.

There will be a div for each venue displaying information for each one.

```
<div class="venue">
  <p class="name"></p>
  <p class="address"></p>
  <p class="phone"></p>
  <p class="tips"></p>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
$.ajax({
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        url      : 'comedy.json',
        jsonp : "callback",
        jsonpCallback: "comedyData",
        success  : function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
            var address = data[i].address;
            $('.address').append(address);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

I am pulling out the data in an array, but need to only populate each venue with just its information.  Venue 1's = name, address, phone...and have a DIV for each venue displaying this information.

I am trying to find a way of making one DIV that will replicate itself with the 30 venues from the JSON file?  So each div will have its Venue name, address, etc but only written once and populates from the JSONP file.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are many venues and performance becomes an issue, you might want to consider using `clone` after all as it looks like it will perform better then my in memory solution I posted.

**OPTION 1**

---

*HTML Markup*

```
<div id="venues">
    <div class="venue" style="display:none;">
      <p class="name"></p>
      <p class="address"></p>
      <p class="phone"></p>
      <p class="tips"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

*jQuery Code*

```
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    var $div = $(".venue:first").clone();

    //set data
    $div.find(".name").html(data[i].name);
    $div.find(".address").html(data[i].address);
    $div.find(".phone").html(data[i].phone);
    $div.find(".tips").html(data[i].tips);

    $div.removeAttr("style");

    //append to main container
    $("#venues").append($div);
}
```

**Edit:** *Was thinking a little more about this because there was a pretty long list of items so I created a JavaScript version (non library dependent) which should give you better performance*

**OPTION 2**

---

*HTML Markup*

```
<div id="venues"></div>
```

*JavaScript No Library*

```
var doc = document;

var fragment = doc.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    var div = doc.createElement("div");
    div.className += "venue";

    var name = doc.createElement("p");
    name.innerHTML = data[i].name;
    name.className += "name";

    var address = doc.createElement("p");
    address.innerHTML = data[i].address;
    address.className += "address";

    var phone = doc.createElement("p");
    phone.innerHTML = data[i].phone;
    phone.className += "phone";

    var tips = doc.createElement("p");
    tips.innerHTML = data[i].tips;
    tips.className += "tips";

    div.appendChild(name)
       .appendChild(address)
       .appendChild(phone)
       .appendChild(tips);

    fragment.appendChild(div);
}

doc.getElementById("venues").appendChild(fragment);
```

Comment: I like this solution but for some reason the data from the JSONP file is not populating the classes?  I am not getting any data?

Comment: @Xtian are you saying that the `data` parameter returned in your success function is empty?

Comment: I see results in my console but the data is not populating the p.class's.  Take a look: http://bit.ly/zUlcjZ

Comment: it might be something with using .html()

Comment: @Xtian there is a mistake in the markup template. Copy the HTML from my answer again and it should work. Currently on your test page, the outter `div` has a `class` of `venue` and is hidden but the outer `div` should have an `id` of `venues` and not be hidden. The div with class `venue` on the inside is the one that should be hidden.

Comment: I simplified the test page, and have it laid out the way you have it, but still no results? =(

Comment: @Xtian Sorry! I have a typo in my solution...there is a `#` sign in the `venues` id. remove that and you'll be good. I've also updated the other solution as well.

Comment: @Xtian was thinking about this and how there seemed to be quite a few items to loop over. So I've created a second version which does not rely on jQuery and should perform better.

Answer (score 1):

I've added a container to add all venues to:

```
<div id="venues" />
```

Create the template in memory:

```
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    var $div = $("<div class='venue'><p class='name' /><p class='address' /><p class='phone' /><p class='tips' /></div>");

    //set data
    $div.find(".name").html(data[i].name);
    $div.find(".address").html(data[i].address);
    $div.find(".phone").html(data[i].phone);
    $div.find(".tips").html(data[i].tips);

    //append to main container
    $("#venues").append($div);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can create the div and p dynamically in javascript, in order to repeat the result from your json data. for example:

in html:

```
<div id = "venues"></div>
```

in javascript:

```
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++)
{
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var p1 = document.createElement("p");
    $(p1).html(data[i].name);
    var p2 = document.createElement("p");
    $(p2).html(data[i].address);
    $(div).append(p1);
    $(div).append(p2);
    $("#venues").append(div);
}
```